# Describe changes in atmosphere data - mathematical solutions

Tags: climate-change, climate-models, mathematics

I interpolated isotopic data (2H or 18O) from 1970 and plotted it on a map. I did the same with data from 2010. The interpolated data are gridded data which have changed over time. Up to now I have only used the Chi-square test as a stochastic evaluation! I wanted to ask you if there are other stochastic or mathematical methods to describe a change in climate data?

I am still new in this field and would be happy about even seemingly simple mathematical laws, but more complex ones are also good!